# Image processing (segmentation) in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, retina

How can I detect optic cup and disc from retinal image using matlab ? I want to find out the measurement of optic rim ( distance between optic cup and optic disc )

[image: Click here to See the Sample Image that need to be processed]

I have tried the following code

```
RGB  = imread('img/A(4).jpg');
G = DialateBloodVessel(RGB);
[BW,H] = RGBThresh(G,220,60);
H = H(:,:,3);
I = edge(H,'Roberts',0.1);
imshowpair(I,G);

%%%%%%%%%% DialateBloodVessel( RGB ) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function [ RemovedBV ] = DialateBloodVessel( RGB )
%UNTITLED3 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
IM = RGB;
SE = strel('disk',10);
IM2 = imdilate(IM,SE);
%SE2 = strel('disk',10);
RemovedBV = imerode(IM2,SE);
end

%%%%%%%%%% RGBThresh(RGB,Ch1,Ch3) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function [BW,maskedRGBImage] = RGBThresh(RGB,Ch1,Ch3)
I = RGB;

% Define thresholds for channel 1 based on histogram settings
channel1Min = Ch1;
channel1Max = 255.000;

% Define thresholds for channel 2 based on histogram settings
channel2Min = 0.000;
channel2Max = 185.000;

% Define thresholds for channel 3 based on histogram settings
channel3Min = Ch3;
channel3Max = 255.000;

% Create mask based on chosen histogram thresholds
sliderBW = (I(:,:,1) >= channel1Min ) & (I(:,:,1) <= channel1Max) & ...
    (I(:,:,2) >= channel2Min ) & (I(:,:,2) <= channel2Max) & ...
    (I(:,:,3) >= channel3Min ) & (I(:,:,3) <= channel3Max);
BW = sliderBW;

% Initialize output masked image based on input image.
maskedRGBImage = RGB;

% Set background pixels where BW is false to zero.
maskedRGBImage(repmat(~BW,[1 1 3])) = 0;

end
```

I get the following output, but I need perfect circles in any image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at your image, I notice two important things:

- Color is not that useful (which is often true), because everything is rather red. So, transforming to grayscale is a good idea.
- The circle you want to select is charaterised by a large intensity change, rather than a high intensity. Therefore, calculating gradients may be useful.
- Small blood vessels have high gradients too. So, your `DialateBloodVessel` may be useful.

---

```
RGB = imread('0PBEL.jpg'); % load the image
% I crop the image to remove the black background (which gives high gradients too)
RGB = imcrop(RGB, floor([.2*size(RGB, 2) .2*size(RGB, 1) .6*size(RGB, 2) .6*size(RGB, 1)]));
G = rgb2gray(RGB); % convert to grayscale
G = DialateBloodVessel(G); % remove blood vessels

grad = imgradient(G); % calculate the gradient magnitude (direction is not important)

%display the (transformed) images: useful to validate method and tune parameters
figure
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(RGB)
subplot(2, 2, 2);
imshow(G)
subplot(2, 2, 3);
imshow(grad, [])
subplot(2, 2, 4);
imshow(grad >= 20, [])

% calculate the centroid and radius of all the regions
stats = regionprops('table',grad >= 20,'Centroid', 'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength');      
centers = stats.Centroid;
diameters = mean([stats.MajorAxisLength stats.MinorAxisLength],2);
radii = diameters/2;
[maxRadii, iMax] = max(radii); % select the largest circle

subplot(2, 2, 1);
viscircles(centers(iMax, :),maxRadii); % visualise the selected circle
```

[image]

---

As an alternative, you can use the builtin `imfindcircles` functions as follows:

```
[centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(G,[50 100]);
figure
imshow(RGB)
hold on
viscircles(centers, radii,'EdgeColor','b');
```

Note that this method may work, but has the disadvantage of being a black box.

[image]

Comment: As you can see my Image I need to separate 2 Circles , Inside white area should be segmented also, and another thing, I want this algorithm works for any image. Not only on this particular image.. I am very new at Image Processing so I don't have any idea how to do it .. If you can help pls...

Comment: I showed you an example of how you can possibly do it. It is up to you to tune this method to your needs. Test the method with different images, and try to tune the parameters to become a satisfactory result.