# Which algorithm to use to segment out an object with grayscale similar to background?

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3seCh.png]

I have to detect an object very close to ground. It has most area similar to road surface in terms of grey scale, but visually it has a proper shape. I tried with manual thresholding, image filling and contours. But no good results. Contours are worst. My aim is to get a binary image with the object as foreground (white).

Comment: [Edge-detection](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html#canny-edge-detection-in-opencv) might work. Can you add the image? We'll be able to help you better.

Comment: Using a similar approach as I demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176667/image-processing-segmentation-in-matlab/44180934#44180934) may work.

Comment: Thanks J.D. and m7913d. But, both of your answers do not seem to fit in this problem. I have attached the image link above. I believe, a systematic sequential basic image preprocessing should be our answer. But, I am unable to find that sweet spot (:-

Answer (score 0):

That is a small image :p

This is how I approached your problem: first I detected the edges in the image. Next I used [morphological closing](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#closing) to join lines that are close together. This works very well on the outer edges, the outline of the shape. Then the contour of this shape could be detected (cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL returns only the outermost contour). Because of some noise I added a size threshold, and the remaining contour is drawn filled on a new image.

I added a second option, that is more efficient, but might not work for the rest of your project, because it is less flexible for other images. Here the edges are taken and a large morphological closing is done, which joins together the entire shape. To remove the noise a smaller morphological opening is then performed. As you can see below, the results are nearly identical, though the difference may be bigger for other images.

Final note: if this mask is too crude, you can use the mask to cut out the relevant area of your image and use this to create a better mask.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

# load image 
image = cv2.imread("image.png")
# detect edges in image
edges = cv2.Canny(image,100,100)


#option 1: use contours
# solidify / join edges
kernel =  np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
# create black image with the size of image
result = np.zeros(image.shape[:2])
# detect contours in the mask (outer edges only)
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw contour 
for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100:
        # draw filled contour in white on result
        cv2.drawContours(result, [cnt], 0, (255), -1)
        # draw outline of contour in red on original image
        cv2.drawContours(image, [cnt], 0, (0,0,255), 2)


#option 2: morphology only
# solidify / join edges
kernel2 =  np.ones((20,20),np.uint8)
mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel2)
# remove noise 
kernel3 =  np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
result2 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel3)


# show image and results
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
cv2.imshow("Result_option1", result)
cv2.imshow("Result_option2", result2)
# release recourses
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```