# Removing Noise from an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image that has line on it and some dots as well. What is the best way to get rid of that noise without damaging the image too much ?

I have tried thresholding and blurring the picture, however it seems the line and the dots are too thick for it to actually work.

Here is the image i played with:https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2IE1.jpg

And these are the filters i have tried:

```
gussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5,5), 0)
averaging = cv2.blur(image, (3,3))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. It's be helpful if you can include what you've tried so far and specifically what problems you are having. You might want to try reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: You can try using [findContours()](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html) to create a mask ([example in this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266354/which-algorithm-to-use-to-segment-out-an-object-with-grayscale-similar-to-backgr/54276565#54276565)). You can disregard the contours with a contourArea smaller than a threshold. This way  you can remove most of the dots, but the line remains...

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you're trying to solve a simple captcha image, right? [Here](https://github.com/ptigas/simple-captcha-solver) you can find the simple captcha solver. Perhaps it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link slawomir, however i just need help in removing noise from a picture such as this image. I have tried basic filters as:
    averaging = cv2.blur(image, (3,3))
    gussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5,5), 0)

Comment: As you said, the dots are too big to be considered as noise. You can use findContour command and get the size of the contour of every objects in the image, and remove the small ones. For the line, you can use Hough transform to detect and remove it.

Comment: I will try it later and update, thanks for the help!

Comment: The most robusr way - semantic segmantation with dnn (u-net, mask rcnn etc)